# Angular JS filters working unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search

I'm trying to filter a list of json data (https://api.myjson.com/bins/5a2aw) using an Angularjs filter. When I just use filter exact matching does not take place and for 1 shows results with id = 1,10,11,12. Using true with filter though works very weirdly, a single result whose id is 7 appears for all ids.

```
 <html>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names |  filter : true : {id: 7}">
    {{x.Name+ " " + x.Quote}}
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $http){
        $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/5a2aw").success(function(response) {$scope.names=response.records;});
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `true` (which is exact check) after a [**`filter`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) criteria, not at the 1st place of filter.

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names |  filter : {id: 7}: true ">
    {{x.Name+ " " + x.Quote}}
</li>
```

**Syntax**

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LZLTnF4xT92E3TJUohXE)

Code:

```
ng-repeat="x in names.records |  filter : {id: 1} : true"
```

Comment: what is the difference in your answer..same as that of mine :p

Comment: You have beat me here :p

Comment: Its 5 minutes difference :p